Databases as children of blocks
I'm mainly wondering if there's any way of:

getting around this limitation by a series of API calls (though it doesn't seem like that's the case to me); or
if there's any plans to allow this in the future that anyone knows of.

Above all, I'm trying to duplicate a page via the API and child_database objects are a massive thorn in my side. The page I'm trying to duplicate has several such databases that are children of pages so duplicating those is straightforward, but there are a few that are children of blocks.
Seems like a kind of strange restriction to include considering how easy it is to do via the UI.

unfortunately, as of now, there isn't a straightforward way to completely get around this limitation using a series of api calls. you can go with partial automation to retrive parent page content and then en programmatically recreating the structure and content where possible but the specific handling of child databse nested within block should be handled manually.
